# Can't get simple self-sizing collection view cell to size to label using autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, constraints

Xcode 10.2, Swift 5.

I've got a `UICollectionViewCell` defined in a `.xib` file. I load that in my `UIViewController` (not `UICollectionViewController`) subclass and return it in `cellForItemAt`.

In my `UICollectionViewCell` (called `TagCell`), I do this:

```swift
    override
    func
    awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.354, green: 0.442, blue: 0.297, alpha: 0.74).cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
    }
```

The Nib has only the top-level `UICollectionViewCell` that I dropped in, and a `UILabel` with fixed 4-pixel constraints to all four edges. I set the text of the `UILabel` in `cellForItemAt`. However, the resulting collection is rendered with all cells at the estimated height I set in `viewDidLoad()`:

```swift
    override
    func
    viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "TagCell", bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self)))
        self.collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TagCell")

        let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 60.0, height: 25.0)
}
```

Cell Nib File:

[image: Cell Nib Screenshot]

This seems to be anything Apple and other resources I found online tell me to do, but I must be missing something crucial. I've also tried setting the horiztontal compression resistance priority to 1000 on my UILabel, but they keep getting truncated.

I aso tried putting in a `>=` width constraint, but that appears to be ignored.

Before I set `self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, I would get the conflicting constraints warning in the debugger. But now it doesn't complain about the `>=` width constraint, even thought it's violating it.

Comment: Could you add the storyboard image

Comment: @pooja I posted the cell nib, I think that's what's useful, right? The UICollectionView is just a single view inside my UIViewController's main view.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out you *must* do the following in your cell’s `awakeFromNib()`:

```swift
        self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let fixupConsts =
        [
            self.contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor),
            self.contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor),
            self.contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            self.contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
        ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(fixupConsts)
```

Despite the fact that [WWDC 2014 Session 226](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/226/) very explicitly states the only thing you need to do is set `estimatedCellSize` to a non-zero value, it’s simply not enough.

If anyone can provide a better answer, I'll gladly mark it as the answer.